# How to airtap, hold and move in hololens emulator

Tags: hololens-emulator

How to "airtap, hold and move" in hololens emulator, especially in the direction in and out of the monitor? I am able to do airtap using right mouse button, but unable to achieve hold and move.

Can someone help me here?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

**Walk forward, back, left, and right** - Use the W,A,S, and D keys on your keyboard, or the left stick on an Xbox controller.

**Look up, down, left, and right** - Click and drag the mouse, use the arrow keys on your keyboard, or the right stick on an Xbox controller.

**Air tap gesture** - Right-click the mouse, press the Enter key on your keyboard, or use the A button on an Xbox controller.

**Bloom gesture** - Press the Windows key or F2 key on your keyboard, or press the B button on an Xbox controller.

**Hand movement for scrolling** - Hold the Alt key, hold the right mouse button, and drag the mouse up / down, or in an Xbox controller hold the right trigger and A button down and move the right stick up and down.